# Listview visible child element

Tags: android, listview

In my application  i have used an `"Listview"`. In that what i want is I have to get the `count of the visible child`.
For example if i load that listview in my device first shoes 3 rows ,so i have to show in a textview that `"Showing 3 of 10"`,and when user scroll the listview i have to update that textview according to scroll..I tried a lot but i didn't acheived this..

**I tried for this also:**

```
 int count=0;
for(int i = 0; i  <= listView.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++)
        {
            if(listView.getChildAt(i)!= null)
            {

                count++;  // saying that view that counts is the one that is not null, because sometimes you have partially visible items....
            }
        }
```

Always returning 0. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Y i got the answer....

I implemented onscroll listener..

```
library_listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                firstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem+1;
                String vischild="Showing "+firstVisibleItem+" to "+visibleItemCount+" of "+totalItemCount+"";
                visiblechild.setText(vischild);

            }
        });
```

Thanks a lot..